# Why is MVC page compilation forcing constant app restarts on my Azure web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, restart, precompiled

My precompiled Azure web app is constantly restarting, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here are the details:

- This is an MVC 5 web project published as an Azure web app
- .Net Framework v4.5.2
- The reason for restart is "BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename" with this message: "Change Notification for critical directories. bin dir change or directory rename"
- I added a FileSystemWatcher to figure out which files are changing, and they are always files like "bin\App_Web_h2quortx.dll" and "bin\dailyentry.cshtml.c45ee28a.compiled"
- Under Publish settings, I have selected the "Precompile during publishing" option, which I thought would prevent the pages from being compiled
- Within the precompile configuration, I have tried various options,
  but nothing has worked so far
- This behavior doesn't happen immediately after a
  publish. It looks like it doesn't show up until the app has been visited after an application timeout
- Restarts occur with practically every page view, the first time the
  page is viewed after the application restarts

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you checked out your app pool idle timeout? If there's no request for certain period of time the pool goes idle, then It restarts when some request comes on

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem isn't that the app pool is timing out. The problem is that after it restarts after a timeout, it's dynamically compiling the pages again, which causes the app to restart immediately. This shouldn't happen, because it should have been precompiled.

Comment: are there multiple websites on the same server? do you have an antivirus installed on the server? are your views being dynamically generated?

Comment: does your website uses remote file share to cater to the web requests?

Comment: There is only 1 "WebSite" on this server. There is nohting installed, is PAAS and there is no option for installing something like antivurus...

There is nothing like remote file share. We use "REDIS, ELASTIC DB, MVC"

Comment: you should also look into this issue here might be of some help
https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6526

Comment: did you try adding application insights to see where your dependencies could be causing hang up timeout issue? If your views are recompiling you might want to check if your project file has altered the option for <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>.

Answer (score 2):

though after many attempts i was unable to reproduce the exact same error on my dev machine.

Like caue for your error seems like changing files and [File Change Notifications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/11/01/asp-net-file-change-notifications-exactly-which-files-and-directories-are-monitored/)

1. Make sure there is nothing in your App_Start Code that is changing essentials files on the web app. Like WebConfig, App_Data etc.
2. Try disabling the File Change Notifications

   ```
   <httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" />
   ```

This property resides under configuration->system.web

** - Please note that for some reason i am not being able to fully enter XML markup here in the answer box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also readed about fcnMode="Disabled" , for me it sounds like a hack ?!
=> Interessting is, I can't confirm that I found files where modified after publishing. I tested this with : 

var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.LastWriteTime).Take(3).ToArray();

Comment: (there is nothing in app_data ; we only read values from web.config)

Comment: trying disabling the fcn mode. if this solves your problem we are at least a step closer to recognizing what the problem is

Comment: It looks like that will fix it. How I can find out what's the root cause(...)?

Comment: By knowing exactly what files are causing the restart.

Comment: So we never write something to the FileSystem, only Redis Cache or Elastic Database. As you can see in my post bellow, I try to figure out what file cause this behaivor, but non of thes files are changed.

Comment: Try looking for all the files even the files that are not in bin folder

Answer (score 0):

==> Providing additional informations:

Log:
*Change Notification for critical directories. bin dir change or directory rename HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown Change Notification for critical directories. bin dir change or directory rename Change Notification for critical directories. bin dir change or directory rename HostingEnvironment caused shutdown*

To get the "issuer" I wrote in Application_End the following:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.LastWriteTime).Take(3).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            Log.Info("FILE: " + item.FullName + " | " + item.LastWriteTime);
        }
```

**The LastWriteTime is always the same date, so **I can't confirm there is any modification !?****

I also log the StackTrace:

```
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo) at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand() at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace) at System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnCriticalDirectoryChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e) at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.OnCriticaldirChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e) at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications() at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback) at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

**Edit:**
Thanks for your comment, I changed the code in the app_end to:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(p => p.LastWriteTime).Take(3).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            Log.Info("FILE: " + item.FullName + " | " + item.LastWriteTime);
        }
```

It displays always the same 3 *.compiled files, but the LastWriteTime is equals the publishing date, so what is causing the **"bin dir change or directory rename"** ?

Comment: please add this to your question instead of adding an answer

Comment: it's not my question :(, just same problem.

Comment: the app domain can also restart from any file change for some folders even outside of bin.